# Solenoid control with Injector output

Tags: transistors, mosfet, control, solenoid

I am trying to control a high pressure oil solenoid that modulates clutch pressure for a front/rear torque split in an AWD car. The standalone ECU I am using is made for 8 cylinders but we are only using 6, so I'd like to use a spare injector output for the solenoid. I can set up the output as a PWM that oscillates between ground and open/not connected (not sure of the correct terminology for it). The issue is the output it limited to 1.5A, and the solenoid draws much more than this.

I figure I can use a mosfet or transistor to handle the higher power, but I am not sure how to control it. From my experience, you usually use a high/low to switch a mosfet/transistor, but I'd like to use the open/ground of the injector output. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please excuse my lack of knowledge as I am a filthy Mech E and have found myself well past my electrical bounds.

[image]

Comment: What is the injector input?

Comment: Whoops, meant output, my bad

Comment: How much current does your solenoid require?

Comment: The solenoid uses up to 5 amps